# Need to filter content on page by single array property on user corresponding button click in Angular 2

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, filter

So, I am very confused here. I want to filter books that are already presented on the page by a value of a property from its array and that property is its specific Category(Philosophy, Classic, Poetry, etc...) when user click on the specific corresponding button on the panel.

Here is source-code: https://github.com/EgomortIncognitus/bookstore

This is my first Angular project, and I am quite a beginner in all of this, so I know that StackOverflow is not a "write code for me" service, but I genuinely want to understand this in depth as I do not have a single idea how to do this. Please, if you can provide me step-by-step examples I would be truly grateful to learn from you. Thank you in advance, big time.

Answer (score 0):

You will do the filtering on your **book-listing.component.ts**:

You declare an array of categories which we instantiate with a first value 'All' so later we'll be able to reset the filter and to show all books:

```
categoryArray = ['All'];
```

Then, to be able to go back and forth with filtering we keep the books array only for display filtered books and we declare another booksDatasource array where we are going to keep the books list unmodified, as received from the service. This way, each time we filter on booksDatasource and add the filtered result to books for display.

```
booksDatasource: Array<any> = [];
```

After this, we modify the ngOnInit like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.booksService.getAllBooks()
      .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.booksDatasource = data;
        this.books = this.booksDatasource;
        this.fillCategory(this.booksDatasource, this.categoryArray);
      },
      error => this.error = error.statusText
      );
  }
```

First, we fill the booksDatasource with all data, then we bind booksDatasource to books for the first time to show all books and we call the new added method fillCategory in which we iterate the datasource and extract all categories we have and add then to categoryArray:

```
fillCategory(data, categoryArray) {
    for (const book of data) {
      if (categoryArray.indexOf(book.category) === -1) {
        categoryArray.push(book.category);
      }
    }
  }
```

On book-listing.component.html, we add a new select that will display all the categories we have on categoryArray and we bind onChange event to trigger the categoryChanged() on component:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="sort-field">Category</label>
        <select (change)="categoryChanged($event.target.value)" name="cat-field" id="cat-field" class="form-control">
            <option
            *ngFor="let cat of categoryArray"
            [value]="cat">
              {{ cat }}
            </option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

On the categoryChanged(cat) we pass the selected category from the select and we filter the booksDatasource for books having the passed category and we add them to books array for display:

```
categoryChanged(cat) {
    if (cat === 'All') {
      this.books = this.booksDatasource;
    } else {
      this.books = this.booksDatasource.filter(item => {
        if (item.category === cat) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
      );
    }
  }
```

I forked your repository, added the working code and made a pull request with the changes so you'll have all this working on your repo.